# Как настроить CoreDumpDirectory в apache?

Tags: php, apache, debian, vesta

Периодически на сервере начинают вылазить ошибки в /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Sat Jun 30 16:24:04.235870 2018] [core:notice] [pid 14059] AH00052: child pid 8211 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sat Jun 30 16:24:05.237066 2018] [core:notice] [pid 14059] AH00052: child pid 8213 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sat Jun 30 16:24:08.240572 2018] [core:notice] [pid 14059] AH00052: child pid 8214 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sat Jun 30 16:24:08.240614 2018] [core:notice] [pid 14059] AH00052: child pid 8215 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Чтобы узнать причину, попробовал воспользоваться статьей https://habr.com/company/bitrix/blog/153001/
В командной строке:

```
echo "/tmp/httpd-core.%p" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
ulimit -с unlimited
```

Добавил в /etc/security/limits.conf строку

```
apache - core -1
```

В /etc/apache2/apache2.conf добавил строку

```
CoreDumpDirectory /tmp
```

затем

```
service apache2 restart
```

Однако дампы не создаются после теста:

```
ps aux | grep apache2
…
kill -11 12345
```

, в логах нет подстроки ", possible coredump in /tmp"
Что нужно сделать, чтобы начали создаваться дампы? ОС Debian 8, стоит VestaCP. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите не включен ли apport (/etc/default/apport). Если включен, то отключите его и сделайте опять шаги которые вы выполняли. Просто apport переопределяет политику сбора дампов.

Comment: Нет такого файла "apport" в дирректории /etc/default

Answer (score 0):

Если в Debian 8 используется `systemd` в качестве сервис менеджера, то

- открываете файл `/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service`
- в раздел `[Service]` добавляете строку `LimitCORE=infinity`
- затем `systemctl daemon-reload`
- затем `systemctl restart apache2.service`

Если у вас при этом `cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` равно `/tmp/httpd-core.%p`, то ищите дамп в каталоге типа такого:

`/tmp/systemd-private-9ca2aaa4c9674aafab477c29ff649b2c-apache2.service-mufjX4/tmp`.

Название файла будет `httpd-core.12345`, если выполнялась команда `kill -11 12345`.

При этом в логе Апача будет строка `... [pid 12345] AH00051: child pid 12345 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /tmp`

На Ubuntu 16.04 всё именно так.

Comment: `/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service` - такого файла нет, есть только папка `/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d` с файлом forking.conf